# How to display tabular data in the widget?

Tags: android, widget, tabular

I'm trying to create a simple widget displaying football scores updated from the Internet. My biggest problem so far is how to display tabular data in the widget? I want basically to display scores in lines with 3 fixed width columns in each: 1st name of the first team, aligned to right, 2nd current score, centered, 3rd name of the second team, aligned to left.
I was hoping to use programatically created TableLayout or WebView with properly formatted HTML but neither of these methods can be used in widgets. What would be the best approach to this task?